# Get the solution to echo the one function variable to another in php or wordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have stored a value from the ajax request to the `$passValue` in the `my_ajax_req()` function. Now I am trying to echo the `$passValue` in the `wpsln_log_wp_user_login` function. For this I have coded as below. Also I had tried by using the keyword global in the both function for this variable. But those not worked. Now I am trying by this using session variable. But I can not echo the `$passValue` in the `wpsln_log_wp_user_login()` function.  I do not get where exactly problem is. Please help me out.

If another way to echo that variable `$passValue` in the `wplsn.......()` please help me.

**The html**

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://www.alitabari.com/wp-login.php" method="post">

        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20"></label>
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In">
</form>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
(function( $ ) {
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    var pass_val = $('#user_pass').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'pass_rec',
        value: pass_val
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        alert( errorThrown );
      }
    });
  });
})( jQuery )
```

And **The final PHP**

```
function my_ajax_req()
{
    // global $passValue; I was using but not working.
    session_start();
    $passValue = $_POST['value'];
    echo $passValue;
    $_SESSION['passValue'] = $passValue;
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_pass_rec', 'my_ajax_req');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pass_rec', 'my_ajax_req');

function wpsln_log_wp_user_login($user_user_login, $user)
{
     // global $passValue; I was using but not working.
    $passValue = $_SESSION['passValue'];
    echo $passValue;
    die('Call'); // Remove die when it works 
    // do your further code here if require.
}

add_action('wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', 10, 2)
```

Comment: you never call `session_start()` in your `wpsln....()` function, so unless you call it somewhere else, your $_SESSION will simply be empty.

Comment: I have used the `session_start()` in the `wpsln....()`. But got no result. What problem?

Comment: Your AJAX callback won't fire. You've used a different action name.

Comment: I have updated the codes. That is not working. @Nathan Dawson

Comment: The session variable is not working in  the `wpsln.......()`. I am getting confused why this is happening? Please help me. @Marc B

Comment: Hello this question yet not solved. I am in great need to solve this question.  Please help me. @NathanDawson

Comment: I actually set the session_start() in the `wpsln....()` function. But this is not working. Please help me. @MarcB